# React String filter method returning Empty Array with .includes() conditional

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

When I test example code like this in a sandbox, it works. But when using in my functional component. It does not work.

I am only showing the code necessary to see the example.
`queryValue` state is set when a user types in a search bar and have `console.log(typeof queryValue)` returns a string and console.log(queryValue) to get what is in a field.

`data` is an array of objects I am getting from an API. If `queryValue === ""`, then data shows up ok.

`else` condition when there is something typed in the field, I filter over the `data` (array of objects) and set the `productData` to the result of the `filter()` method. It should only return an array of objects where the title key (which is also a string) `includes(queryValue)`

I have also `console.log(product.title.includes(queryValue));` This returns `true`
At the end `console.log(productData);` and I get an empty array if someone types something...but the condition is `true`.

I read that `filter()` returns and empty Array if nothing matches the condition. But clearly mine does.

`product` in `filter()` is confirmed to be an object

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [queryValue, setQueryValue] = useState(null);

  let productData = [];

  if (queryValue === "") {
    productData = data;
  } else {
    productData = data.filter((product) => {
      product.title.includes(queryValue);
    });
  }

  console.log(productData);

  return (
   <h1>Hi</h1>
  )
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Comment: return `product.title.includes(queryValue);`. Currently you're not returning anything so `undefined` is being returned which is a falsy value and so your `productData` turns out to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
product.title.includes(queryValue);
```

To return true or false:

```
return product.title.includes(queryValue);
```

Or with an implicit return:

```
productData = data.filter((product) => product.title.includes(queryValue));
```